# Create constant size document embeddings by longformer or any huggingface model

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to create 1 embedding of any size (as long as it is the same for all the documents) for long textual documents. My documents have words from 2K tokens to 12K tokens.
I used longformer model from huggingface like this:

```
tokenizer = LongformerTokenizer.from_pretrained("allenai/longformer-base-4096")
model = LongformerModel.from_pretrained("allenai/longformer-base-4096")
encoded_input = tokenizer(text_dataset[0], return_tensors="pt", max_length=4096, truncation=True)
output = model(**encoded_input)
output.last_hidden_state.size() # prints torch.Size([1, 2591, 768])
```

When I rerun this code on a different document I get the size like torch.Size([1, 1820, 768]), etc.

How can I change it or use any other solution (except Gensim's doc2vec model) to get the constant size embeddings for my document? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!